# TextField and Text on same line in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make something like this [Desired Output](https://imgv2-1-f.scribdassets.com/img/document/448837802/original/e38be04002/1671465527?v=1) in flutter. For example: I want something like this: I ___________ hereby says this (then if there's no space left the text will move to next line) and here the _____ should be TextField where I can add my name.

I think text and TextField on the same line. I've tried achieving it in flutter but the TextField doesn't works without adding Expanded or Flexible because it causes Layout error.

Alternatively if there's a way to let user change the text by holding it or somehow like I've this long text in the app and I can leave it to user to change their name or dates etc. that will do too

This is my code but it looks too bad.[image: My output]

```
Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline, // <--
              textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
              children: const <Widget>[
                Text("I"),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Name'),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 8),
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                      'Here the text will come and it will cover up to 10 or more lines and will have textfields in the middle somewhere like in the image.'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        )
```

Comment: Are you wanting the text to wrap under the textField?

Comment: I want something like this: I ___________ hereby says this (then if there's no space left the text will move to next line) and here the _____ should be TextField where I can add name

Comment: Are you allowed to constrain the textboxes with a fixed size? If so, you should be able to wrap the whole thing in a row and use the `Wrap` widget around that to add linebreaks whenever the end of the screen is reached. But like you said, you need to constrain the `textformfields`

Comment: @Dominic Tried `Wrap` but `Textformfields ` doesn't works with it. If you have a solution please provide code snippet

Answer (score 4):

You can use IntrinsicWidth widget to have a flexible TextField size.

```
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    children: <InlineSpan>[
      // first part
      const WidgetSpan(child: Text("Program:  ")),
      // flexible text field
      WidgetSpan(
          child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: const BoxConstraints(minWidth: 64),
              child: const IntrinsicWidth(
                child: TextField(
                    maxLines: null,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        isDense: true,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0))),
              ))),
      // last part
      const WidgetSpan(child: Text("  Index No:  ")),
      // ...
      // ...
    ],
  ),
),
```

- output is like this

[image: output]

Answer (score 2):

So after trying for a while, I ended with this solution. It isn't great and you'll need to figure out the best way to style the `TextFormFields` so they look okay.

Since I constrained them to a fixed size, you'll likely also need to set them individually to a length you find suitable. But it works as intended as far as I can tell.

```
Wrap(
    crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Text("I am a "),
      Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
        width: 150,
        height: 50,
        child: TextFormField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Name'),
        ),
      ),
      Text(" person who likes to "),
      Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
        width: 200,
        height: 50,
        child: TextFormField(),
      ),
      Text(" in my free time.")
    ],
  ),
```

Instead of using many small `SizedBoxes`, I used a `Container` to specify `padding`. This leads to an output looking like this:

[image: wrap]

It might also be worth thinking about if it really makes sense to put `TextFormFields` inline with more `Text` from a usability perspective. In my opinion, they generally deserve their own line on a mobile device.

Comment: Better than nothing but responsiveness is a great issue in this code

Comment: Yeah I know, unfortunately that will always be a problem with what you are trying to achieve. To mitigate it you can use `MediaQuery` but even then it doesn't always make sense to say a field is xyz% of the screen size (think tablets). It's probably best to think about the longest text that somebody will write into it and adjust accordingly. There are likely better ways to do this, but none of them are simple.